# httpmime4.5.1をAndroidで利用するとNoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse

現在開発しているプログラムでjarファイルを扱いたいのですが`NoClassDefFoundError`が出てしまいます。
いくつか調べてlibsファイルにjarを保存し、ビルドパス→ソースでlibsフォルダを追加しました

ライブラリーのところにはビルドパスは通さなくてもいいんでしょうか？
また上記を行わないとプログラム中のインポート文にエラーが出ます。

上記は.classpathの編集で解決しました。
NoClassDefFoundErrorは現在も出ています。
該当箇所はFileBodyの部分です。

解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

開発はEclipseで行っています。

以下ソース

```
public class HttpThread extends Thread{
String muri = null;
public HttpThread(String guri){　//メインから画像のパスを取得
muri = guri;
}

public void run() {
/*▼▼▼BlobKey取得用▼▼▼*/
String url = "http://xxxx.appspot.com/bandroid";
String bkey = "";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    bkey = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
/*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/

/*▼▼▼ＧＡＥアクセス用▼▼▼*/
try {
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    if(bkey != null) {
        bkey = bkey.substring(0, bkey.length()-1);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(bkey);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        Log.v("test", "path=" + muri);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        File file = new File(muri);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        builder.addPart("myFile", fileBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
        httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*▲▲▲ここまで▲▲▲*/
```

}}

Comment: AndroidのEclipse向けプラグインは今では非推奨となっていますが、それはさて置き、いつのバージョンからかは忘れましたが、基本的には`libs`ディレクトリに`jar`を置けば何もしなくとも`Android Dependencies`に追加されます。ただしADT23辺りはライブラリのトラブルがいくつかあります。もう少し詳細な情報は出せますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます
ADTはまさしく２３です。

jarファイルはhttpmime4.5.1を使用しています

Comment: AndroidにあるHttpClientは4.0の開発途上のバージョンなので、4.5.1のHttpComponentは動作しないと思います。4.3のAndroid向け互換用HttpClientと、httpmime 4.3の組み合わせだと動作すると思います。ライブラリの使い方そのものは、`jar`に置くだけで問題ないはずです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます
libsファイルに入れるだけではimport文のjarファイルの場所がエラーに成ってしまいます。ビルドパスを通すと消えます。
原因をご存知でしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ないです、自分の環境では再現しなかったので分かりません。プロジェクト直下の`.classpath`ファイルから`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>`が消える現象があるらしいというのは聞いたことがあるのですが。

Comment: .classpathを確認したところご指摘頂いたpath="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"
の部分が
path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"
になっていました
これが原因でしょうか？

Comment: `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK`は名前通り、Android SDKのパスを見に行くためのものですので、必要です。`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>`を追加しても上手くいかなければ環境に何らかの問題があるのかと思います。ビルドパスを追加する方法も結局やっていることは同じなのですが、ライブラリをアプリのバイナリに含めるため、ビルドパスの設定のOrder and Exportでチェックする必要があります。

Comment: 上記を追加したらlibsに入れるだけでimport文のエラーが消えました！
ですが実行するとNoClassDefFoundErrorが未だ出てきます。

Comment: 具体的に何のクラスが見つからないのかが分からないと回答が難しいかもしれません。質問内容は何度でも編集できます。やりたいことはマルチパートの送信でしょうか？HttpComponentのうち他のjarが必要なのかもしれないです。

Comment: 質問内容の編集を行いました。このような感じで大丈夫でしょうか？
やりたいことはマルチパートの送信です。
エラーにorg.apache.http.mime.entity.content.filebodyと出てくるのでhttpmimeだと考えています。

Comment: 失礼しました、jarが不足しているということはなさそうでした。`httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar`と`httpmime-4.3.jap`の組み合わせでマルチパート送信を行ってみましたが、特にソースをいじることなく送信に成功し、表題の事象は起きませんでしたことを報告いたします。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。
httpclientではなくhttpclient-androidだったんですね。
そこを修正したらNoClassのエラーは消えました。
長い時間お付き合いくださりありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決頂けたみたいですので、回答としてまとめてみます。

## ライブラリの利用方法

EclipseのADTプラグインで作成した新規Androidのプロジェクトには、`libs`というディレクトリが存在し、そこにライブラリの`jar`を置くだけでビルドパスを解決してくれます。

もし何らかの要因で`libs`が存在しない、もしくは`libs`にビルドパスが通っていない場合は、`.classpath`に手動で以下の記述を足すことで解決できます。

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
```

## httpmimeをAndroidで使う方法

Android SDKには、Apache HttpComponentのHttpClientが搭載されていますが、[バージョン4.0の開発途上版](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)で、メンテナンスもされていません。

マルチパートの送信でHttpMimeを利用する場合、4.5.1のHttpMimeですとHttpComponentのバージョン違いによって、`NoClassDefFoundError`が発生します。

- HttpClient for Android 4.3.5
- httpmime 4.3.6

の組み合わせであれば、エラーを回避することができます。

---

[Android 6以降ではHttpClientが撤去](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)されている点にご注意ください（日本語訳だと「削除」になっていますが、ランタイムに存在はしています）。